# Equivalent definition about bounded set in metric space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have read some book they said that "A nonempty subset $A$ of metric space $X$ is bounded if $\sup \{ d(x,y) : x, y \in A \} < \infty$" and another book they said that "A nonempty subset $A$ of metrix space $X$ is bounded if there is a ball $B(x,r)$ such that $A \subseteq B(x,r)$"

I want to show that these two definitions are equivalent. First, I let $A$ be a nonempty subset of metric space $X$ and $d=\sup \{ d(x,y) : x,y \in A \}$. Since $A$ is nonempty set, there is $a \in A \subseteq X$. We let $r=d+1$ and $y \in A$. Then
$$d(y,a) \leq d < d+1=r$$
Thus $A \subseteq B(a,r)$.

I cannot complete another hand. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A\subseteq B(z,r)$ and $x,y\in A$, then $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)\le r+r=2r$, so $\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}\le2r\lt\infty$.

Comment: Do the first direction that I prove is correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof**:  If there is a $B(x,r)$ satisfying that $A \subseteq B(x,r)$, then for any point $a \in A$, $d(a,x) \le r$. So, for any $a,b \in A$, $d(a,b) \le d(a,x)+d(x,b)\le r+r =2r,$ and hence $$\sup \{ d(x,y) : x, y \in A \} \le 2r < \infty.$$ This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \subseteq B(x,r)$ then $D(A)$ = $\sup \{d(x,y): x,y \in A \}$ $\le2r<\infty$.

I think this does the job :)

- the simple rationale being that the diameter of a set cannot be greater than the diameter of the sphere that contains it.